# How can I use a range in VBA where the last cell row is in another cell?

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a button in Excel that calculates a given range (with automatic calculation turned off).

I would normally use this except that I would like the row number of the second cell used to define the range to be pulled from a cell. (in this case the "50" would be in another cell).

Range("a3:ak50").Calculate

I dont know where to start !

Range("a3:ak50").Calculate

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, in case it can be of any use by someone here it is :

```
Dim numrows As Long
numrows = Range("AQ1")
Range("A3:AK" & numrows).Calculate
```